Next auth with Azure is not redirecting to microsoft login
I'm using  "next-auth": "^5.0.0-beta.19"
I have a login button on my "/login" page that calls the function signIn() on button click.  I expected this to redirect the user to  Microsoft so they can login. Instead it redirects to "http://localhost:3000/api/auth/signin?callbackUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Flogin" which includes a button that links to microsoft.  How can I redirect immediately from "/api/auth/signin". I suppose I could programmatically click the "Sign in with Azure Active Directory". However, I'm unsure how to extend the signIn page.

